# SVN update resulting in "RA layer request failed" and "SSL handshake failed: Secure connection truncated"

Tags: svn, subclipse

Occasionally, when I try to do a standard **Update to HEAD** using Subclipse 1.6 on MyEclipse 9.0, I get the following error:

> RA layer request failed
>   svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.example.com/myrepo/myproj/trunk': SSL handshake failed: Secure connection truncated (https://svn.example.com)

For the majority of attempts, updating works just fine. I'm not sure what the failed attempts have in common, though I suspect that they're the ones that contain more changes and therefore take longer to complete.

In the past, when I've gotten this error, I've just run the update again. I've never gotten it on consecutive updates.

What does this error mean, and how can I prevent it from occurring again?

Comment: There's no shortage of Google results for "RA layer request failed" and "SSL handshake failed," but they're of varying quality and there seem to be lots of different causes/situations for these messages. Bottom line, nothing I've seen so far has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You just probably lost your connection to your SVN server.